# python mechanize filling out form

Tags: python, mechanize

I am lost on what I can do to use mechanize to fill out the form of the following website and then click submit.

https://dxtra.markets.reuters.com/Dx/DxnHtm/Default.htm

- on the left side click currency information
- then value dates

This is for a finance class of mine and we need the dates for many different currency pairs. I wanted to get in and put in the date in the "trade Date" and then select what "base" and "quote" I wanted then click submit and get the days. off the next page using beautiful soup.

1). is this possible using mechanize?

2). how do I go about this> I have read the docs on the website and looked all through Stackoverflow but I can't seem to get this to work at all. I was trying to get the form and then set what I want but I can't get the correct forms.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, I am not tied down to mechanize, but just not sure what the best module to use it.

This is what I have so far, and I get ZERO forms to attach a value to.

```
from mechanize import Browser
import urllib2

br = Browser()
baseURL = "https://dxtra.markets.reuters.com/Dx/DxnHtm/Default.htm"
br.open(baseURL)

for form in br.forms():
    print form
```

Answer (score 2):

Mechanize can't find any form on that page. It's parse only html response which you received after request with **baseURL**. When you click on **value dates** it's send another request and received another html for parsing. Seems you should use https://dxtra.markets.reuters.com/Dx/DxnOutbound/400201404162135222149001.htm as **baseURL** value. Also python mechanize doesn't support ajax calls. For more complicated tasks you can use [python-selenium](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/selenium). It's more powerful tool for web-browsing.